# Tableau Action Filters

Tags: tableau-api

I have three sheets in Tableau. Sheet1 is a master sheet on which I want to make filtering. My idea is that if user will click on the value there, data with additional info for corresponding account will show up.

I have created two Action filters - one connecting Sheet1 to Sheet2 and the second one to connect Sheet1 to Sheet3. This approach works - when I click on the value in my master sheet, Tableau jumps to Sheet2 where I see the data for this account, also, when I manually go to Sheet3 data there is correctly filtered as well.

The problem starts when I create a Dashboard consisting of those three sheets. I want users to be able to click on the value in master sheet and see additional info from other two sheets in one view. For some reason, when add all three sheets into the Dash, only Sheet2 responds to clicks from Sheet1. Sheet3 remains unchanged.

Do you know what could be the reason that this stops working when all sheets are in the same Dashboard and works otherwise?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the same fields to filter across the views? If yes, you can add one dashboard action to filter from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 & Sheet 3.

FYI...dashboard actions are different that worksheet actions.  Make sure you add the actions on the dashboard using: Dashboard -> Actions.